# MySQL - Inserting rows while avoiding duplicatiions

Tags: mysql

I currently have two tables. One fairly large and one suitably small.
The large table is made up of many inserts from tables in the same style as the small one.

I want to insert (probably using *insert into*) the records from the small table into the big table **IF** they are not already present in the big table.

**Points of Note**

- Both tables have identical column titles so my attempts at joins aren't working (Error Code 1060 - see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins under 'Left-Excluding Join' for the syntax I was using)
- The tables do not have (and can not be given) a primary key / Unique Key
- Rows are identical if and only if each column store the same value

Comment: 4th point of note should be that you're offering a bounty for slapping the moron who designed such a table. No primary key? Good luck hacking this, I know I'd beat the living s*** out of the idiot who made me work with such a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `not exists`:

```
insert into bigTable(col1, . . ., coln)
   select col1, . . ., coln
   from smallTable s
   where not exists (select 1
                     from bigTable b
                     where b.col1 = s.col1 and b.col2 = s.col2 and . . .
                    );
```

Note:  this does not work for `NULL` values.  Well, it does "work", but you will get duplicate rows, which is consistent with the meaning of `NULL` as "unknown" (as opposed to "missing").

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly (and the hint about NULL results is very useful as well!)